# Bash script to automate copying between two folders

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a script to automate the copying of one folder's content to another.

I need to overwrite the contents on the destination folder with the new files.

Is there any existing tool which I could use?

It would be better if it's a command line tool.

If not, can someone give me a hint on how to create such a script?

---

#### Edit: 20-May-2014

I made this:

```
#!/bin/bash

main_dirs=();
j=0;
while read line
do
    ((j += 1));
    if [[ j -eq 1 ]]; then
        output_app_dir=$line;
    elif [[ j -eq 2 ]]; then
        input_app_dir=$line;
    else
        main_dirs+=($line);
    fi
done < publish.config

cd $input_app_dir;

for i in "${main_dirs[@]}"
do
  rsync -arvR --info=COPY ./$i "$output_app_dir"
done
```

with this "config file" that's just a plain text file:

```
/home/rikytres/warda/dplus-moncler/public/javascripts/app
/home/rikytres/warda/box/public/ImportBox/app
controller/box/
view/box/
store/box/
model/box/
[EOF]
```

It's a really bad solution, I know, but I'm not really good as Bash Script developer... :(

---

## UPDATE

I'm using this script as well in MacOSX, and it works!

Comment: What is your operating system? Is that ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry... Yes, ubuntu, but it will be good if it run also on macos

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/). The man page is quite long, but don't let that scare you.

In its simplest form it's just:

```
rsync --recursive source/ destination/
```

You can try out the different options with `--dry-run`, so as to see the results without it actually doing anything.

You might want to use the options `--verbose` and `--progress` to get some feedback.

Comment: rsync is exactly what I was looking for.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: if you want to share files, there are several different protocols of interest: Samba (SMB), NFS, FTP, SSH/sFTP/SCP. Samba is the easiest if a Windows computer is involved, but you can use it also between two Ubuntu (and even Mac OS) machines. SSH is a nice thing for Ubuntu, because it's a very powerful tool - e.g. running rsync over SSH is a command method to keep two directories synchronised.